# get relative path in codeigniter file upload class config array

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, relative-path, absolute-path

I have been using Codeigniter for a project and I have used quite some libraries including File Uploading Class library. I know how to upload and setup `$config` array for uploading.

What I am stuck in is the way codeigniter file upload saves file path, it is saving the absolute path of my machine in database when I am using the `$config['full_path']`. I am setting the value of `upload_path` to `'uploads/documents'` and in database it is saved like `path/to/xampp/path/to/project/uploads/documents`, but I only want the path from root of my application so I can access it in `href` as now when I use it, it shows like `localhost/project/path/to/xampp/path/to/project/uploads/documents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just saw that I misunderstood your question, but that's a job for FCPATH too. Just use it for replacing to get a relative path:

```
var_dump(str_replace(FCPATH, '', $upload_path));
```

This is environment friendly and will work at several machines.

I wasn't able to test my code because I am on my mobile right now, but feel free to ask further questions regarding my solution

**Original Answer below that line, maybe it safes someone time and it has some further informations about the names constans:**

Use the CodeIgniter given constants for that Job.

`FCPATH` links to the same directory where your index.php is located and `APPPATH` links to your Application folder.

This is environment friendly and will save you some work if you move your project to another Server.

Here an example:

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/documents';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

That would point in my case to: `/var/www/myapp/uploads/documents`

Note, this works only that way if you don't autoload the upload library. If you do check the initialize Method in the upload class docs.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#setting-preferences

I can't see linenumbers on my mobile but both constants get defined in the index.php and should be worth a look for you to understand what they contain:

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/index.php

Comment: thanks really elegant solution, but I thought being widely used framework such as CI should have this functionality bu default.

Comment: CodeIgniter ist designed to have a very small footprint and to let you do stuff in the way you like it to be, so i can live with that. To be honest, i have defined a helper function for that, so i don't have to think about it again.

Answer (score 1):

In `constants.php` in `/config` I defined `ROOT` as:

`define('ROOT', realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));` you could probably use `FCPATH`, I just prefer using my own in case I need to change anything.

Then I use this function in my image handler model:

```
/**
 * Replaces ROOT in path with empty value
 * /var/www/images/this.jpg to /images/this.jpg when /var/www is ROOT
 * 
 * @param string $path
 * @return string Rel path
 */
public function get_rel_path($path) {
    return str_replace('\\', '/', str_replace(ROOT, '', $path));
}
```

and save `/images/this.jpg` in the database so I don't have to call this function whenever I want to display an image. If you need to check if a file exists its simple with `if(is_file(ROOT . $somefilefromdb)) { }`

For uploads and anything requiring a full path just use `ROOT . '/uploads/'`